# What's the purpose of the epilogue's cloud?

Tags: braid

In the epilogue there is one last cloud that doesn't seem to do anything. Since I read<sup>1</sup> about that one star where another slowly slow cloud is relevant, I wonder if something similar is the case here or whether it's just an homage to the other castles?

[image]

<sup>1)</sup>but didn't find the motivation to wait for yet...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, according to [Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/gaming/news/a284605/jonathan-blow-discusses-braid-epilogue.html#article_continue), Jonathan Blow confirmed it's rather cosmetic meaning:

> One of the game's mysteries was a stationary cloud positioned beside the castle in the epilogue, which Blow explained has no impact on
>   gameplay.
>
> "There are Braid conspiracy theorists out on the internet who swear
>   that this cloud is for something, and the reason that they think that
>   - and there's a very good reason to think that - is that pretty much everything else in the game has a reason," [Jonathan] explained.
>
> "The reason why this cloud is here is not very verbalisable to me.
>   It's something about victory, it's something about having a beautiful
>   vantage point that I can just stand on, and feel successful about. It
>   just felt right that my castle not only encompasses some blocks that
>   were made, but also some elements that were previously antagonistic to
>   me.
>
> "I just wanted to be in a position where I could look down on the
>   text. I wanted to be high up looking down. Just when I build a castle
>   like this, or added a rampart, it just didn't feel the same. So again,
>   it's a pattern break, it's like everything in the game means something
>   except for this."
>
> He added: "I guess I've never answered that officially, but there is
>   no gameplay purpose to this cloud."